# Resources for adventuring building support

Tags: dnd-5e, adventure-writing, online-resources

I am a new DM using D&D 5E, and I am building my first adventure.  Stack exchange is a great resource for answering specific questions, but is there a good forum out there for getting broader feedback on my adventure?  I am looking for a place where I can put my outline out there and have a conversation about workability, pitfalls I've overlooked, or ways to improve.  Specifically, I am concerned about things like length, difficulty of encounters, and keeping my players engaged.  Any good communities out there for this?

Comment: This might belong on meta instead of on main.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first and obvious forum to check out is [Wizards of the Coasts' own DM Help Forum](http://community.wizards.com/forums/132306).  WOTC's forums tend to have a lot of good advice about specific stats, numbers and rules, overall.  [Enworld's D&D forums](http://www.enworld.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?506-D-amp-D-5th-Edition) tend to be among the best, with a good range of people covering everything from the nitty gritty to the larger flow of things. [Reddit's game forums](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/) tends to collect a range of folks - going from very knowledgable to... well, you'll have to sort for quality and ignore the less helpful responses.

I don't spend a lot of time on OSR forums ("Old School Renaissance" - a lot of D&D fans who prefer the older editions or variants.), but in some places you can find [people doing amazing analysis of the flow and design of older adventures](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?168563-Dungeon-layout-map-flow-and-old-school-game-design), which is a pretty good thing to check into.  [Here's a page with some links to various OSR forums](http://www.batintheattic.com/oldschoolsurvey.htm).

My own two cents for general things to focus on when you're starting out is to look to making sure individual encounters are balanced and fun, that what the party should be doing next is clear and direct, and to figure out what kind of play your group is into - more action, high drama, investigation, etc.  A lot of the more advanced theory in adventure design is about large scale concerns to look at after you've gotten a good grasp of basic scene to scene flow.

Comment: I've been over on the Enworld forums for a few days now, and I have been getting some amazing support.  The members are almost all knowledgeable and helpful.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Glad to hear! It'd be cool to see a link to the thread(s) you might have going on.